# Call waiting not working on Lumia 535

Tags: 8.1, calls

When I am trying to call someone who's already in a call I don't get the "call waiting" message on my screen. This makes me retry again and again.

What should I do?

Comment: Did your operator tells the same by voice?

Comment: As far as I know Call waiting is for your phone. So if you are talking with someone and this option is enabled another incoming call would ring too instead of just say that you are in another call.